# Send a message from my computer to the ESP32 using Bluetooth

Tags: python, bluetooth, esp32

I'm attempting to send a string message from PyCharm on my Windows PC to an ESP32.
PyCharm code is:

```
import asyncio
import bleak


async def run():
    esp32_address = "e8:31:cd:ac:fe:62"

    async with bleak.BleakClient(esp32_address, timeout=30.0) as client:
        characteristic_uuid = "6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E"

        # Sending a message to ESP32
        message_to_send = "Hello, ESP32!"
        await client.write_gatt_char(characteristic_uuid, message_to_send.encode())
        print(f"Sent: {message_to_send}")


# Running the event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

And the ESP32 code is:

```
from machine import Pin, Timer
from time import sleep_ms
import ubluetooth


message = ""

class ESP32_BLE:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
        self.timer = Timer(0)
        self.name = name
        self.ble = ubluetooth.BLE()
        self.ble.active(True)
        self.disconnected()
        self.ble.irq(self.ble_irq)
        self.register()
        self.advertiser()

    def connected(self):
        self.led.value(1)
        self.timer.deinit()

    def disconnected(self):
        self.timer.init(period=100, mode=Timer.PERIODIC, callback=lambda t: self.led.value(not self.led.value()))

    def ble_irq(self, event, data):
        global message

        print(f"Received Bluetooth event: {event}")
        print(f"Received Bluetooth data: {data}")

        if event == 1:  # _IRQ_CENTRAL_CONNECT
            self.connected()

        elif event == 2:  # _IRQ_CENTRAL_DISCONNECT
            self.advertiser()
            self.disconnected()

        elif event == 27:  # _IRQ_GATTS_WRITE
            try:
                _, handle, _, value, _ = data
                print(f"Received GATTS_WRITE event. Handle: {handle}, Value: {value}")
                
                if handle == self.rx:
                    message = value.decode('UTF-8').strip()
                    print(f"Received message: {message}")
                    # Handle the received message here
            except ValueError as e:
                print(f"Error handling GATTS_WRITE event: {e}")







    def register(self):
        NUS_UUID = '6E400001-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
        RX_UUID = '6E400002-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'
        TX_UUID = '6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E'

        BLE_NUS = ubluetooth.UUID(NUS_UUID)
        BLE_RX = (ubluetooth.UUID(RX_UUID), ubluetooth.FLAG_WRITE)
        BLE_TX = (ubluetooth.UUID(TX_UUID), ubluetooth.FLAG_NOTIFY)

        BLE_UART = (BLE_NUS, (BLE_TX, BLE_RX,))
        SERVICES = (BLE_UART, )
        ((self.tx, self.rx,), ) = self.ble.gatts_register_services(SERVICES)

    def send(self, data):
        self.ble.gatts_notify(0, self.tx, data + '\n')

    def advertiser(self):
        try:
            address = self.ble.config('mac')
            print("ESP32 Bluetooth Address:", ':'.join('%02x' % b for b in address[1]))
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error getting Bluetooth address:", e)

        name = bytes(self.name, 'utf-8')
        adv_data = bytearray(b'\x02\x01\x02') + bytearray((len(name) + 1, 0x09)) + name
        self.ble.gap_advertise(100, adv_data)
        print(adv_data)
        print("\r\n")

# Main part of your code
led = Pin(2, Pin.OUT)
relay = Pin(15, Pin.OUT)
ble = ESP32_BLE("ESP32")

while True:
    if message:
        print("Received message:", message)
        message = ""  # Clear the message after printing
    sleep_ms(100)
```

I getting the following:

Received Bluetooth event: 1

Received Bluetooth data: (0, 0, )

Received Bluetooth event: 21

Received Bluetooth data: (0, 256)

Received Bluetooth event: 27

Received Bluetooth data: (0, 15, 0, 960, 0)

Received Bluetooth event: 27

Received Bluetooth data: (0, 48, 0, 960, 0)

Received Bluetooth event: 2

Received Bluetooth data: (0, 0, )

Received GATTS_WRITE event. Handle: 15, Value: 960

Received GATTS_WRITE event. Handle: 48, Value: 960

I am currently grappling with the challenge of understanding how to effectively utilize the EVENT and DATA components in my ESP32 code to display the messages sent by my PyCharm code running on my PC. Can someone provide guidance or support with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Paulo Pimenta - it's going to be difficult to get help if you're not clear about what you want help with. "I'm having difficulty with a task. Can someone lend a hand?" What is the task? If there's a problem with the output that you're getting, what is the problem? What are you expecting to happen? Please edit the question to include a clear question - what are you actually asking?